# CASE WHEN Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have multiple tables and I am performing `JOIN` on them. I want to group them on the conditions that a certain field begins with certain letters and then group them by region. This is how I went about

```
SELECT
  CASE    
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'F%' THEN 'F'
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'CE%' THEN 'CE'
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'CXT%' THEN 'CXT'
  END AS p_by_type
, COUNT(*) AS p_by_count
FROM (
    SELECT [xml_P].Id, [xml_P].PNumber, [xml_PSR].ScopeRegion, [xml_SR].RegionCode
    FROM [xml_P]
    JOIN [xml_PSR]
    ON [xml_P].Id = [xml_PSR].Pol
    JOIN [xml_SR]
    ON [xml_PSR].SR = [xml_SR].Id) PWithRegions
GROUP BY 
  CASE
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'F%' THEN 'F'
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'CE%' THEN 'CE'
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'CXT%' THEN 'CXT'
  END
GO
```

The above code gives me COUNT without taking region into consideration. How should I go about if I want the counts for each `PNumber` beginning with F,CE,CXT for each unique `[xml_SR].RegionCode`. That is for `[xml_SR].RegionCode = AMER` I want counts of F, CE, CXT and then for `[xml_SR].RegionCode = CH` I want the same and so on.

Executing the nested query:

```
SELECT [xml_P].Id, [xml_P].PNumber, [xml_PSR].ScopeRegion, [xml_SR].RegionCode
FROM [xml_P]
JOIN [xml_PSR]
ON [xml_P].Id = [xml_PSR].Pol
JOIN [xml_SR]
ON [xml_PSR].SR = [xml_SR].Id
```

Id, PNumber, ScopeRgion, RegionCode
1 , F586, 42, EMEA
..
22 , CE86, 42, EMEA 
..
44 , CXT6, 42, EMEA 
..
101 , F56, 42, EMEA
..
105 , F996, 43, CH
..
122 , CXT186, 43, CH 
..
44 , CXT196, 43, CH 
..
101 , CE5556, 43, CH
..

and executing the complete query gives me a result set something like this:

p_by_type, p_by_count
F , 39
CXT , 258
CE , 77

What I would like the output to be is

F, 25, CH
F, 3, EMEA
..

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `RegionCode` to the `GROUP BY`.  However, your query is overly complicated -- no subquery is needed:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p.PNumber LIKE 'F%' THEN 'F'
             WHEN p.PNumber LIKE 'CE%' THEN 'CE'
             WHEN p.PNumber LIKE 'CXT%' THEN 'CXT'
        END) as p_by_type,
       sr.RegionCode,
       COUNT(*) AS p_by_count
FROM xml_P p JOIN
     xml_PSR psr
     ON p.Id = psr.Pol JOIN
     xml_SR sr
     ON psr.SR = sr.Id
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN p.PNumber LIKE 'F%' THEN 'F'
               WHEN p.PNumber LIKE 'CE%' THEN 'CE'
               WHEN p.PNumber LIKE 'CXT%' THEN 'CXT'
          END),
         sr.RegionCode;
```

Notes:

- Tables aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The subquery is not needed.
- You should include whichever region code you want in both the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.
- The use of escape characters such as `[` just clutters the query, if they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can juste add RegionCode in your select, and in your group by.

so you will get the count for each RegionCode in each PNumber.

```
SELECT
  CASE    
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'F%' THEN 'F'
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'CE%' THEN 'CE'
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'CXT%' THEN 'CXT'
  END AS p_by_type
, RegionCode
, COUNT(*) AS p_by_count
FROM (
    SELECT [xml_P].Id, [xml_P].PNumber, [xml_PSR].ScopeRegion, [xml_SR].RegionCode
    FROM [xml_P]
    JOIN [xml_PSR]
    ON [xml_P].Id = [xml_PSR].Pol
    JOIN [xml_SR]
    ON [xml_PSR].SR = [xml_SR].Id) PWithRegions
GROUP BY 
  CASE
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'F%' THEN 'F'
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'CE%' THEN 'CE'
    WHEN PNumber LIKE 'CXT%' THEN 'CXT'
  END, RegionCode
GO
```

Comment: Tried that but got this error: *is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

Comment: hm.. See the answer of @GordonLinoff bellow that is better :)